# Prove $f(x) = x^2 + 3$ is continuous at $x=3$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

Prove that $f(x) = x^2 + 3$ is continuous at $x=3$.

I have tried using $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon + 9} - 3$.

I tried to split $|x^2-9| = |(x-3)(x+3)|$ and tried to make $x+3$ in terms of $\delta$.

But I get $\delta^2 + 6\delta$.

I don't really get what I'm doing wrong or right so I need some help with finding the right $\delta$.

Also, I cannot really understand the goal of the proof, I read on elsewhere that I need to make $\delta$ as small as possible?

Comment: You might want to recheck your title, you have written some plain text in mathjax by mistake.

Comment: There is no need to make $\delta$ as small as possible. What is the problem with $\delta^2+6\delta$? $|(x+3)(x-3)|<\delta^2+6\delta$ so if we choose $\delta>0$ such that $\delta^2+6\delta=\varepsilon$ then for $|x-3|<\delta,|x^2-9|<\varepsilon$. The above yields $\delta=\sqrt{\varepsilon+9}-3>0$.

Comment: Wait, I thought I'm supposed to end up with $\epsilon$ at the end? I think my struggle is I don't understand how to actually prove. So I didn't understand what to do with $\delta^2 + 6\delta$

Comment: The goal of such a proof is to show the existence of a $\delta$ corresponding to an $\epsilon$ such that some specific implication involving these symbols is true. You don't have to find large or small $\delta$, but just any $\delta$ which works. But in general solving inequalities is the wrong approach here. For example use of square roots in expression for $\delta$ is circular. Existence of square roots involves continuity of $g(x) =x^2$ and is essentially equivalent to continuity of $f$.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2487862/72031) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve the equation

$$0<|x-3|<\delta\implies|(x^2+3)-(3^2+3)|<\epsilon$$ for $\delta$.

As the function $x^2+3$ is monotonic around $x=3$, you can solve the equation

$$|x^2-9|=\epsilon$$ and use any $\delta$ such that $(3-\delta,3+\delta)$ is wholly contained between the two solutions, $x=\sqrt{9\pm\epsilon}.$ (Other possibilities are $x=-\sqrt{9\pm\epsilon}$, but this does not straddle $x=3$.)

The largest value of $\delta$ is thus

$$\min(\sqrt{9+\epsilon}-3,3-\sqrt{9-\epsilon})$$
and this is always $\sqrt{9+\epsilon}-3$.

---

**Check:**

$$-\delta<x-3<\delta\implies3-\delta<x<3+\delta\implies x^2<(6-\sqrt{9+\epsilon})^2,(\sqrt{9+\epsilon})^2.$$

But

$$(6-\sqrt{9+\epsilon})^2=36-12\sqrt{9+\epsilon}+9+\epsilon\ge 9-\epsilon$$

because

$$36+2\epsilon\ge 12\sqrt{9+\epsilon}$$
$$1296+144\epsilon+4\epsilon^2\ge 1296+144\epsilon$$

and $$\epsilon^2>0.$$

Comment: Sorry just to clarify, where does the $(6- \sqrt{9-\epsilon})^2$ come from? Isn't $\delta =\sqrt{9 + \epsilon } - 3 $. Thanks

Comment: @jeff: indeed, so what is $3-\delta$ ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(6 - \sqrt{9 + \epsilon}$ instead. Cause I'm also having trouble grasping the part on largest value and the min.

Comment: @jeff: ooops, you are right.