# Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0-}e^x=1,$ using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0-}e^x=1,$ using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

This means we need to show that, $\forall\epsilon\gt 0,\exists \delta \gt 0$ such that, if $0\lt -x\lt\delta$ then, $|e^x-1|\lt\epsilon.$

Now, $|e^x-1|\lt \epsilon\iff 1-\epsilon\lt e^x\lt 1+\epsilon.$ But $e^x\gt 1-\epsilon$ is always true. So, the task is to find a $\delta $ such that if  $0\lt -x\lt\delta\iff -\delta\lt x\lt 0$ then, $e^x\lt 1+\epsilon.$

This is the part, where I am stuck. I don't know how to proceed further. If we take log on both sides of the inequality, $e^x\lt 1+\epsilon,$ then we get, $x\lt\ln (1+\epsilon),$ but this is not what we desire.

Comment: Using any definition of $e^x$ first prove that $e^x\geq 1+x$ (or use this result directly) and then for $x\in(-1,0)$ we have $|e^x-1|=1-e^x\leq - x=|x|$ so that $\delta=\epsilon$ works.

Comment: In general while trying to write $\epsilon, \delta$ proofs regarding limits or continuity of some function $f$ it is desirable to avoid any use of inverse function $f^{-1}$ for calculation of $\delta$. The existence of an inverse is usually dependent of continuity of original function and hence it may lead to a circular argument. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2487862/72031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\forall \epsilon>0$ sufficiently small, there exists $\delta = -\ln(1-\epsilon)>0$ such that for $-\delta<x<0$ we have
$$|e^x-1|<\epsilon.$$